# How to I connect Xbox 360 to monitor?

Tags: xbox-360

So I've tried a VGA to HDMI and i just saw that it wouldn't work. If i get a xbox 360 vga hd av cable will i get sound? I don't see the white and red ports on my monitor and i dont think there is  speakers on it but will it still work? (with sound) I know i could get a converter also but will that also have sound?

Comment: VGA only carries a video signal, so the red/white RCA connectors (or optical?) are required if you want to get sound while using VGA; if your monitor has an 1/8" speaker line input, however, you could use an RCA->1/8" adapter. (That aside, if your monitor doesn't have speakers on it, how could it possibly emit sound?)

Comment: i only have a dvi and vga ports

Comment: so that adapter will only work on monitor or the xbox?

Comment: If your monitor doesn't have any audio inputs at all, your only option to get sound would be to use some kind of separate speakers or headphones.

Comment: so can that adapter rca one connect to the s pdif port on xbox?

Answer (score 2):

If your monitor does not have sound, then no.. you will not get sound through the 360 VGA cable.

VGA does not carry a sound signal, the sound branches off either to a left/right (red and white) cable or a single jack depending on the particular cable you get. Some of them also have a port on them for optical out, which could be used to direct the sound to a surround sound system or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I use a monitor with my setup without speakers. If you are using the HDMI (digital video and audio) output on your xbox, you still have the S/PIDF TOSLINK connector to carry sound. If your monitor does not have speakers, most likely it also does not have an HDMI connection, only a DVI connection. As long as your DVI connection can carry digital signal (very, very likely) you can use an adapter to change the HDMI to a DVI connection for your monitor, leaving only sound left.

You can use the extra sound connection to port your digital audio to a computer, a sound system, or anything else that supports it.

Comment: If your monitor is VGA, Xbox sells a VGA adapter that has RCA audio outputs as well. http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-VGA-HD-AV-Cable/dp/B000B6MLTG

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hdmi cable straight from the monitor to the xbox and it will work. That is my current set up. Also if your monitor has sound it will play through it.